# Easy way to add a number as an image in a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm creating a checkerboard pattern as follows:

```
def CheckeredBoard( x=10 , y=10 , sq=2 , xmax = None , ymax = None ):
    coords = np.ogrid[0:x , 0:y]
    idx = (coords[0] // sq + coords[1] // sq) % 2 
    if xmax != None: idx[xmax:] = 0.
    if ymax != None: idx[:, ymax:] = 0.
    return idx
ch = CheckeredBoard( 100, 110 , 10 )
plt.imshow2( ch )
```

What I would like is to add a number in some of the boxes to number them so that when I run `plt.imshow2( ch )` I get the numbers be part of the image.

The only way I can think of doing this is by using some sort of annotation and then saving the image and loading the annotated image but this seems really messy.

For example a succesfull matrix would look like:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

The matrix above has a 1 and an 8 in the two corners.
[image]
Appreciate any help, let me know if you want additional information.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is something closer to what I'd actually like to end up with.

Red circles added for emphasis.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) command?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to use it, because I actually want to create a matrix that is like that, I'm not interested in creating a pretty plot. The only way I can think of using `annotate` is as I describe which seems too messy...

Comment: If you want to be able to get `plt.imshow(...)` to do it, it's going to be a hell of a lot messier.

Comment: well in the end of the day I'll want the matrix, so you think `annotate` then `plt.savefig` then `plt.imread` is the way to go?

Comment: You only care about the matrix? and the plot is purely for convenience viewing? Do you want the value for every cell to be loaded? are are the annotations separate from the plot. Can you post an image of what you would like to achieve (made in paint/gimp/whatever) ?

Comment: on a side note, `idx = (coords[0] // sq + coords[1] // sq) % 2` is horrible, and a real kick in the balls to future you.

Comment: I tried to do that with the current, image, I'll post a better example shortly

Comment: I didn't realise they were `0` and `1` in the square!! sorry! i'll rethink the question.

Comment: ok added another image, hopefully clears any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using PIL / Pillow?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

#-- your data array
xs = np.zeros((20,20))

#-- prepare the text drawing
img = Image.fromarray(xs)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text( (2,2), "4", fill=255)

#-- back to array
ys = np.asarray(img)

#-- just show
pylab.imshow(ys)
```

Comment: bingo, yes this is what I was after!

Comment: just a quick question, if I want to do a loop do I include the `d = ImageDraw.Draw` in the loop or only the `d.text( )`

Comment: You should keep the 'd = ImageDraw.Draw' outside the loop. This statement just gets you a drawing context, which can be re-used with any number of drawing statements. Keeping this line within a loop would mean unneccessary work load and use of memory.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
n = 8
board = [[(i+j)%2 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]


from matplotlib import pyplot
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


ax.imshow(board, interpolation="nearest")

from random import randint

for _ in range(10):
  i = randint(0, n-1)
  j = randint(0, n-1)
  number = randint(0,9)

  ax.annotate(str(number), xy=(i,j), color="white")


pyplot.show()
```

[image]

obviously you'll have your own way of locating the numbers, and and choosing them, other than that though, the annotate functionality has everything you need.

You might need to offset the numbers, and in that case you can either just have a set size and work out how much you need to offset them by, or you can work out the bounding box of the squares and offset them that way if you want.

Colouring the numbers you also have a few options - you can go with a standard colour for all, or you can opposite colour them;

```
for _ in range(10):
  i = randint(0, n-1)
  j = randint(0, n-1)
  number = randint(0,9)

  colour = "red"
  if (i+j)%2 == 1:
    colour = "blue"

  ax.annotate(str(number), xy=(i,j), color=colour)
```

[image]

but honestly, i think the white option is more readable.

Comment: but this doesn't give me the matrix I want right? I mean I'll still have to do the `plt.savefig` etc right? I may just go with that though

Comment: Oooh, in that case just save the matrix as plain text with a bit of extra data, or look at the `pickle` package. I have to go out now, so maybe someone else will pick up where i left off.

Comment: hopefully I figure it out or someone gets that last bit, thanks